# ranking elements of vectors in a data frame

Tags: r, ranking

please help me with this, I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                 G2=c("a","c","b","d","e"),
                 G3=c("a","d","e","b","c"),
                 G4=c("a","b","c","d","e"))
```

And i would like to produce another table showing the position of each term from G1 to G4, so it can look like this:

```
rank <- data.frame(term=c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                   G1=c(1:5),
                   G2=c(1,3,2,4,5),
                   G3=c(1,4,5,2,3),
                   G4=c(1:3,4,5))
```

My second question: is there a graphical way to conect each element accross the table, say, an arrow for "b", going from [2,1] to [3,2] to [4,3] to [2,4)

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have applied the suggestions in my original data frame. This is an example of it:

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("bta-let-7a-1","bta-let-7b", "bta-mir-26a-1", "bta-mir-21"), 
                 G2=c("bta-mir-21", "bta-let-7a-1", "bta-let-7b", "bta-mir-26a-1"),
                 G3=c("bta-mir-26a-1", "bta-mir-21", "bta-let-7a-1", "bta-let-7b"), 
                 G4=c("bta-let-7b","bta-mir-26a-1", "bta-mir-21", "bta-let-7a-1"))
```

The problem is that when I `lapply`, the column "G1" becomes "1","2","4","3".

```
rank <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.integer))
```

However, I which to have "G1" as "1","2","3","4" and that the rest the other columns arrange according to "G1". For example, that "G2" were "4", "1", "2", "3". (this gets way messier in my original table)

Comment: sapply(df, as.numeric)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have factors already, it's simple to do:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, as.integer))
#  G1 G2 G3 G4
#1  1  1  1  1
#2  2  3  4  2
#3  3  2  5  3
#4  4  4  2  4
#5  5  5  3  5
```

If you want to reorder your factors as in the edited OP, one way to do it would be:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(lapply(df, function(x)
                  factor(as.character(x), as.character(df$G1))), as.integer))
```

Comment: And for the second part, if you load `library(MASS)` you can do `parcoord(rank)` if you assign `rank <- as.data.frame...` as suggested by @eddi

Comment: Thank you. How can I see the terms "a","b","c","d","e"? (in the table and in the graph?

Comment: @Sergio.pv perhaps use `levels(unlist(df))`? It's a little hard to say what the best way of extracting that info is (not enough information is given for that), but it would work for the OP.

Comment: I have a very large list of names (~600 names) which are present in 4 groups at different positions (postion 1 to ~600). The possition in each group are important for data interpretation, therefore the need to see how one term changes accross the four groups.

Comment: @eddi I've tried to use axis(2, at=0:4, labels=letters[1:5]). I don't get output "a","b","c","d","e" for each line, just "a" on the bottom of the graph and "b" at the top

Comment: @Sergio.pv I think you want `axis(1, ...)`